# simple sql: how do I group into separate columns?

Tags: sql, transform, pivot, pivot-without-aggregate

Say I keep stocks prices in a 3 column table like this:

```
create table stocks(
    ticker text,
    day int,
    price int
);

insert into stocks values ('aapl', 1, 100);
insert into stocks values ('aapl', 2, 104);
insert into stocks values ('aapl', 3, 98);
insert into stocks values ('aapl', 4, 99);

insert into stocks values ('goog', 1, 401);
insert into stocks values ('goog', 2, 390);
insert into stocks values ('goog', 3, 234);
```

And I want results that look like:

```
day aapl goog
1   100  401
2   104  390
3   98   234
4   99   null
```

Do I really need to select twice, once for each ticker, and then outer join the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
Select day,
   MAX(case WHEN ticker = 'aapl' then price end) as 'aapl',
   MAX(case WHEN ticker = 'goog' then price end) as 'goog'
From stocks
group by day
```

### [**DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61367)

Comment: @FahimParkar, I think he his the same downvoter who downvotes our two posts in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157638/how-to-transform-vertical-fields-in-a-table-to-horizontal-result-by-sql, you also got a downvote for yours too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157638/how-to-transform-vertical-fields-in-a-table-to-horizontal-result-by-sql/9157701#9157701, seems like someone gone mad with two of us, but he didn't downvotes yours in this one, however our two answers are the same in two questions.

Comment: I didn't tried your this solution at that time... but it run smoothly... thanks I tested this time... might help me somewhere...

Comment: @FahimParkar, Doesn't matter at all, the important thing is the OP got a helpful answer(I hope so), doesn't matter whether it gets vots up or down.

Comment: @FahimParkar, you can try it as I pointed in the demo page: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61367

Comment: right :) OUR main AIM is solved, that is it.... Always happy to help.... and I would say your solution is perfect... NO joins and other tricky part... plain and simple... easy to digest (especially for newcomers) :)

Comment: hmmmm.... are there any cons to using this method vs using the DB's pivot feature (if it has one)?  I like this more b/c my favorite relational database (sqlite) doesn't have pivots.

Comment: @user1481, no and it is also working for both MYSQL, and MSSQL and for MSSQL you can use `PIVOT` operator, but note that the problem with your query is that there is no aggregate column to aggregate your data with, so i used `max` as workaround, and the same if you used the `pivot` operator you will need to use an aggregate function.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of the database you are using, the concept of what you are trying to achieve is called "Pivot Table".

Here's an example for mysql:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table

Some databases have builtin features for that, see the links below.

SQLServer:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms177410.aspx

Oracle:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_pivot_examples.htm

You can always create a pivot by hand. Just select all the aggregations in a result set and then select from that result set.

Note, in your case, you can put all the names into one column using concat (i think that's group_concat in mysql), since you cannot know how many names are related to a `ticker`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do, unless your DB has SQL extensions for pivoting. [Here's how you do it in Microsoft SQL Server.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)